# Pusher returns no data with laravel 8 event

Tags: events, laravel-8, pusher, broadcasting

I'm using laravel 8, and I'm having a hard time getting the data from the event using pusher. I'm want to broadcast the event, i want to receive the data when the data is successfully inserted in the database. hope someone can help me with this. here are my codes

config/app.php

```
/*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class
```

Events\Chat.php

```
class Chat implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('chat');
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'get-chat';
    }
}
```

chat.blade.php

```
var pusher = new Pusher('dec355f1ff67f51f5784', {
            cluster: 'ap1',
            forceTLS: true
        });
        Pusher.logToConsole = true;
        
        $('.chat-send').click(function(){
            var msg = $('.chat-msg').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: add_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: {'msg' : msg},
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.msg == 'success') {
                        var channel = pusher.subscribe('chat');
                        channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(data) {
                            //alert('successfully subscribed!');
                            console.log(data);
                        });
                        channel.bind('get-chat', function(data) {
                            //console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                            alert(data);
                        });
                    }
                },
                error : function(request, status, error) {
                    //swal("Oops!", "Seems like there is an error. Please try again", "error");
                }
            });
        });
```

MessageController

```
public function create(Request $request, Messages $messages)
    {
        $request->merge([
            'teacher_id' => 2,
            'student_id' => 1,
            'message' => 'test msg'
        ]);

        $data = $messages::create($request->all());

        if ($data->exists) {
            $msg = 'success';
            $cars = ['hey', 'yow'];
            broadcast(new Chat($cars));
        }

        return json_encode(['msg'=>$msg]);
    }
```

This is what I get in the pusher.log

```
Pusher :  : ["Event sent",{"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"","channel":"chat"}}]

Pusher :  : ["Event recd",{"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"chat","data":{}}]
```